# Change gas amount in Truffle 4

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-config

In Truffle 4, I am performing the migration in `truffle develop` by using the `migrate` command in the console.

However it gives the error

```
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

How can the gas used be changed? I think it requires editing `truffle.js`? What is the name of the network created when using `truffle develop` which gives testrpc listening to port 9545?

Comment: I am suffering from something similar. I have compiled a new function in my contract and when I go to execute MetaMask jumps up with 0 Units in its gas limit. Unlike the other function of my dApp which will automatically fill the field.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the gas provided in truffle.js.
Also, have in mind that truffle 4 has the optimizer turned off by default, so you'll probably want to turn it on if the contract still doesn't get deployed.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If using the testrpc provided by `truffle develop`, will you change the `port` to `9545`? for the `gas` value to take effect?

Comment: All the information is also provided [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration). I haven't encountered the `solc` part that you mention in your answer, but it looks very interesting so I'll have a look. You forgot to mention that the default for `gas` is 4712388, and you also forgot to mention the `gasPrice` option (with its default being 100000000000).

Comment: One more thing - I found that `"localhost"` can lead truffle to fail on some operating systems (namely Windows), when the network is disconnected. In order to resolve this problem, you can simply replace it with `"127.0.0.1"`.